How to increase the maximum number of simultaneous connections/streams (.net grpc)
I have a grpc service written in .net, set up on docker, when trying to connect with more virtual users (over 500) an error occurs:
ERRO[0002] GoError: connection error: desc = ‘transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:43333: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.’running at reflect.methodValueCall (native).

Kestrel configuration didn't help.
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.Http2.MaxStreamsPerConnection = 10000;
});

With the number of users at 100-200 this problem does not occur and the script executes without any problems. I tried turning off firewall. The error also occurs on the standard .net grpc project.
Here’s my program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ChatRoomService>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGrpcService<ChatService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client.");

app.Run();


Can your .net service handle 500 concurrent connections?

@knittl I think it can handle, at most I was able to connect a little more than 2500 vus, but it is never the same amount.

"because the target machine actively refused it" means that the server/server process refused the connection. It's not a problem to be fixed in k6

@knittl I understand, I am currently in the process of looking at how to increase the number of connections to the server, but there is a bit of a lack of material on the internet.
